# How can polar plots of radiation fields/array factors be made by hand?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, antenna-array

In one of my courses we are expected to plot array factors and other radiation fields by hand. I am comfortable deriving expressions for the array factor by hand but I am struggling when trying to plot them.

The book describes a method that involves plotting cos(φ/2) where φ = Bdcos(θ) + α and drawing circles under the graph, but I don't understand it. If anyone could help me with this via explanation and an example I would greatly appreciate it as the resources I have found for this online typically just use tools like Matlab and I have to do it by hand.

Comment: The book you mention; is it something you don't want to reveal?

Comment: You want a "method" to plot the polar patterns, or you want someone to explain the "specific method in your book"?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of amplitude vs angle, you just need to plot these points on paper. Polar graph paper would be best (just Google it to get a source for printing it). Even without polar graph paper, a ruler(for laying out the amplitude) and a protractor (to set the angle) are sufficient to make a graph. This is what we did years ago when PCs were not around.